# How is Medic healing conducted in Dark City Games' Legends RPG?

Tags: skills, healing, legends-of-ancient-world

The Medic skill description reads, "Can be used across multiple characters."

What does that mean, exactly? Seems to me it could either mean that someone with Medic 3 could roll once and if he succeeds, can split up to three points of healing between different injured comrades, or it could mean he gets to roll for each companion and on each success, heals 3 from each companion he succeeded with.

And what if there is more than one Medic in a party? Can each medic roll, or is there a limit of one medic per patient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I dug up an answer on the Dark City Games forums, from 2012 ([link to post here](http://darkcitygames.proboards.com/post/1866/thread)). A developer answered:

> Post by mister frau blucher on Sep 3, 2012 at 6:47am
>
> ---
>
> Good question, h3rne!
>
> As with many of our rules, given their brevity, they produce some grey areas.
>
> But the levels in Medic definitely apply to the IQ check. So an IQ12 dude with Medic+3 would roll against a 15.
>
> I think the rest of the description might cause more confusion, when it says, "can be used across multiple characters." This might imply that your skill of +3 may be used with one character or distributed across the lot - that is, there are 3 total hits to be healed, split as you desire. I actually played this way for a while, until I came to the conclusion it didn't make much sense. If your medic skill is +1, why would you be able to sew up a small cut on one dude, but not another? So **you can apply your full skill to each dude**.
>
> Bret

So apparently the developers didn't really think through the details, and changed their mind from one interpretation to another, without ever making the rules clear.

From other answers on the forum, while they know their super-short rules leave some grey areas and they are interested in improving that, they also often answer something like "play however you prefer" rather than giving an authoritative way to play.

Other players opined that it doesn't make sense unless **there is** at least **a limit of one healer per victim**.

I *can* also think of a reason why one healer couldn't heal everyone, which could be *time* after which first aid would be too late because others were being healed first, but since the developers clearly didn't consider this, it seems up to the players to pick/invent interpretations of the healing rules they like. It would also seem to make sense if medieval healers weren't as able as healers in far future settings.